# Graph API Drive Items: Retrieving latest version id when listing items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I would like to retrieve the latest file version identifier for each file when listing the contents of a folder, or when asking for metadata for a single drive item.

The [`DriveItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/resources/driveitem) does not contain any `version` information, versions are retrievable for single items only with an [additional API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_list_versions) call.

Doing an additional API call for each file when I'm listing a folder that has several files in it is something I want to avoid.

Is there an efficient way to retrieve the latest version id for a listing (or single file), without having to do additional API requests, and especially without having to do *n + 1* requests in the case of folder contents listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$expand=versions` query option to query for all the versions alongside the DriveItem information. This will list out all the versions on that item and you can select the first one to get the latest one.

A sample graph explorer query would look like following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}?$expand=versions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of calls by using [JSON Batching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching). This would allow you to return the `versions` for up to 20 files at a time.

One technique would be to set `$top=20` on your `/children` query and then submit a batch request for each of the `DriveItems`. Once your batch completes you can request the `@odata.nextLink` for the next page and repeat the batch process. This reduces your calls to only 2 per page of data.

Comment: I take it JSON batching is limited to at most 20 requests?

Comment: It is according to what I found at [Known Issues](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#json-batching)

Comment: It is unfortunate that there's no efficient way to get versions without artificial limitations. I will accept it since that's probably the best way to do this right now.